# C++20 modules - Cannot export const and constexpr

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, constexpr, c++-modules

I try to use C++20 modules in GCC compiler for STM32 microcontrolers. The issue I face is that I cannot export any constant or constexpr declared in the module:

sys_defs module:

```
export module sys_defs;
```

```
export const int abc = 0;
```

main.cpp:

```
import sys_defs;

void main()
{
   if (abc == 0)                  // compiler error: error: 'abc' was not declared in this scope
   {
       // do some stuff here
   }
}
```

What do I do wrong ?

When I export regulars functions, classes etc. it works ok. But I always get error when trying to export constants and constexpr.

Comment: I would like something which works like "#define abc 0" in a header file.